# Configure the connection string for multiple windows service

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

I am having `multiple windows service` in my current project. And all are having different `app.config` files & `connection string` is defined in the same config file.

Now I want to update the `app.config` in such a way that all the windows services share the connection string from the single file.

My directory structure is as given below :

RootFolder ->

1. Service A
2. Service B

I have tried using below 2 approaches but didn't work out :

1. `AppSettings's "File" attribute.` - Is there anything can be done that
   I can assign the few key value's in AppSettings section & I can use
   those in connectionstring section.
2. `ConnectionString's "ConfigSource" Attribute` - This attribute contains only relative path so it is not working for me.

Thank you so much in advance. Let me know if any further information is required.

Answer (score 0):

One method can be using a symbolic link for the common app.config file.

So you put the common app.config file containing the connectionStrings section somewhere accessible by all services and in your services' installation directories you create a symbolic link pointing to that file using [mklink](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194.aspx)

Such as:

```
mklink common.app.config.link "C:\Root\App.config"
```

And in the app.config of the Windows services you point to that link:

```
<connectionStrings configSource="common.app.config.link">
</connectionStrings>
```

It requires a bit maintenance but I guess it can be automated as well if you put mklink command in a script.

Hope this helps.

UPDATE:
Common app.config : X:\common.app.config
Project 1 Installation Path: X:\Project1\
Project 2 Installation Path: X:\Project2\

1. In X:\Project1\ create the link

   mklink common.app.config X:\common.app.config
2. In X:\Project1\App.config file update the configSource

So bottomline is in configSource you give the path of link which is pointing to the actual file. If you're only providing the name of the link make sure it's in the same folder as you exe file, as shown in the image

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for replying back. I have create a link using mklink but now the problem is when I m trying to fetch the connection string in c#, I am getting the error like this : "Unable to open configSource file common.app.config". now how to over come with this ? Please advice on same. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user509685 - I reproduced that exception and that happens when it cannot find the shortcut I created. Could you please make sure you in configsource you're entering the name of the link you used in mklink (i.e common.app.config.link in my example). Also please make sure the link and exectuable are in the same folder or you have to change the path of the link too

Comment: I have created link as given below. mklink "db.config" "D:\db.config" and now my project is in D:\Project\WindowsService this path. And in configsource I am giving path like this : configSource "db.config" So now when I am running the project & getting the error which I have mentioned above. Let me know if I am doing anything wrong.

Comment: @user509685 - I updated my answer to address the path confusion. I'm sorry if this is still not clear enough. I guess you just have to play around with the paths

Comment: @Volkman : I understand that the exe & the file has to be on same path. But I have multiple windows service and all are on the different path. So I want to create a single file for connection which can be access from the other paths as well. Any help is appreciated with this.

Comment: Then you have to create the link under every project folder. I'm not a Volkman by the way :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85094/discussion-between-user509685-and-volkan-paksoy).